# How to change css with jquery that show msg error "has no css method"?

Tags: jquery

I found a element in facebook that I can't change the css in the console.

something like this ~> `$('globalContainer').css('width', '90%')`;

with or without # *$('#globalContainer')* returns the div... and in both cases show the menssage error "has no css method". It's no just about the css modification, it's about the error.

Comment: looks like `$` is not jQuery!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div id="globalContainer" class="uiContextualLayerParent">
```

---

[ID Selector (“#id”)](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

```
$('#globalContainer').css('width', '90%');
 //^
```

---

Read http://api.jquery.com/ and http://learn.jquery.com/

---

Sir [Arun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114251/arun-p-johny)  is Absolutely right

$ is not jQuery here.

Instead use Vanilla Js

```
document.getElementById('globalContainer').style.width='90%'
```

Comment: $('globalContainer') or $('#globalContainer') show "has no css method" when a call ..css('width', '90%') but only $('globalContainer'), or $('#globalContainer'), returns the div to console.

Comment: Ok... irrespective of whether the element is there or not if `$` is jQuery then a jQuery object will be returned which will have the `css()` method... then why the error

Comment: @ArunPJohny Sir you absolutely right it's not jQuery.It's working with Vanilla js

Comment: @EdDominikie Use JavaScript `document.getElementById('globalContainer').style.width='90%';`

Answer (score 1):

### Expand on your question.

First of all, you're selecting a tag named globalContainer. There's no such html tag. You'll need to do $(".globalContainer") if its a class, or $("#globalContainer") if its an id.

**I'm not sure this question really relates to anything...**

Expanding on this, google chrome has developer tools that allow you to change css properties. I recommend a free class from codeschool on google dev tools.

Comment: Ok... irrespective of whether the element is there or not if `$` is jQuery then a jQuery object will be returned which will have the `css()` method... then why the error

Answer (score 0):

Learn basic of jquery selector:

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

you have wrong in your selector:

```
$('globalContainer').css('width', '90%');
```

here what is `globalContainer` ?

css class name? then it should be like this:

```
$('.globalContainer').css('width', '90%');
```

id? then it should be like this:

```
$('#globalContainer').css('width', '90%');
```

Comment: Ok... irrespective of whether the element is there or not if `$` is jQuery then a jQuery object will be returned which will have the `css()` method... then why the error